# New extension and wiring. Speakers cut out when something is turned on/off

Tags: electrical, wiring

My father recently had a new extension done to his house. (British, early 80s, if that helps)

One wall was removed, and moved backwards to extend the lounge.
This involved new wiring being installed to replace the previous wiring that was in the removed wall.

Since its completion, he has found that when something is turned on/off that is connected to the new wiring, it can, and often *does* cause his Bose speaker system to cut out for a few seconds before it comes back.

An example of a device that does this is his new electric fireplace, which causes this just turning on/off the lighting effect (heater off) or when we plugged in a string of Christmas lights to test them when putting up the decorations.

This only happens (as far as we have seen, at least) with the new sockets.  The other, pre-existing sockets in the room do not seem to affect it in the same way, nor did this problem exist when plugged into the old, now removed, sockets.

It is a minor frustration, but as we do not understand the cause, we are concerned about any possible damage to equipment that may be plugged in, the sound system, or something else.

What could be a possible cause of this issue?
What are the potential issues that could arise from whatever could be causing it?
Finally, what steps should be taken to mitigate or eliminate this issue?

Comment: Can you just turn the heater on the "fireplace" on/off without turning on the lighting effect?

Comment: "what steps should be taken to mitigate or eliminate this issue?" As it's a recent extension you should get the contractor back to fix their faulty wiring.

Comment: Just a guess but check where the new wiring joins the old system there is possibly a bad connection or breaker. Consider hiring an electrician to check this out, since it was done in the 80's I would not expect a warranty.

Comment: @Gil it was all done by an electrician, and the fuze box isn't that old and has been replaced with breakers.  I'm wondering in what way turning off a light could cause this to happen, if it's as you describe?

Comment: A bad connection, loose wire are a few things that would cause this. I normally do not suggest hiring help if it can be avoided but you also have a potential fire hazard, depending on what the fault actually is. You narrowed it down to the interface between the old and new wiring. Somewhere they are connected together. You might place a lamp in the same plug as the sound system and see if it stays on steady or blinks when you dld what caused to shut down before.